# Does the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra follow from the real Spectral Theorem?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, general-topology

I found a slick way to prove that every real normal matrix is orthogonally equivalent to a block diagonal form consisting of diagonal parts and $2 \times 2$ parts of the form $$\begin{pmatrix}a & b \\ -b & a\end{pmatrix}.$$

This seems awfully close to proving FTA - if every real polynomial is the characteristic polynomial of a normal matrix, then every real polynomial consequently splits over $\mathbb C$. So my question is:

**Is there a  slick way to find a real normal matrix given a characteristic polynomial?**

Note that the companion matrix is not normal in general.

Comment: Added topology because I used compactness of $S^n$ in my proof of this. So I'm not averse to a topological procedure for this question.

Comment: Just as a sanity check, if you've already used compactness of $S^n$, then you've used enough analysis to prove FTA, so it's reasonable to expect you can finish with just easy algebra.

Comment: @EricWofsey I hesitantly agree.

Comment: So, for what it's worth, just doing brute force calculations in the $2\times 2$ case, the result is not true over $\mathbb{Q}$ and to prove it over $\mathbb{R}$ you very much need to use the fact that every positive real has a square root.  This suggests that the general case might not really be any easier than proving FTA.

Comment: @EricWofsey Good catch on it not being true over $\mathbb Q$. Feel free to post that counterexample and I'll go ahead and accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An algebraic solution *cannot* exist; you can adjoin the eigenvalues of rational symmetric matrices to $\mathbb Q$ to obtain a field which satisfies the spectral theorem (symmetric matrices diagonalize orthogonally) but is not a real closed field.

**Definition.** Let $F \subseteq K$ be an extension of ordered fields. Then $\alpha \in K$ is *symmetric* over $F$ if $\alpha$ is an eigenvalue of a symmetric matrix with entries in $F$. $K$ is a *symmetric extension* of $F$ if every element of $K$ is symmetric over $F$.

**Lemma.** Let $A$ be an $n \times n$ symmetric matrix over an ordered field $F$, and let $p, q \in F[x]$ be coprime polynomials. Then $\ker p(A)$ and $\ker q(A)$ are orthogonal subspaces of $F^n$, and therefore intersect trivially.

*Proof.* Let $ap+bq=1$ and use the substitution $a(A)p(A)$ to assume WLOG that $p(x) = x$ and $q(x) = 1-x$. Then use the fact that the kernel of a symmetric matrix is orthogonal to its image.

**Lemma.** A symmetric matrix over an ordered field is semisimple.

*Proof.* Apply the spectral theorem to a real closure of the field of coefficients.

**Theorem.** Let $A$ be a symmetric matrix over an ordered field $F$. Then $A$ is orthogonally equivalent to a block diagonal matrix in which each block has irreducible characteristic polynomial.

**Lemma** Let $A, B$ be symmetric matrices over an ordered field $F$, of size $n \times n$ and $m \times m$ respectively. Then polynomials in $A \otimes I_m$ and $I_n \otimes B$ witness the fact that the symmetric elements of $K$ in an extension $F \subseteq K$ form a subfield of $K$.

**Lemma** Let $F \subseteq K \subseteq L$ be a chain of extensions of ordered fields. If $K/F$ is symmetric and $L/K$ is symmetric, then $L/F$ is symmetric.

Thus we can speak of a "symmetric closure" of $\mathbb Q$ in $\mathbb R$, consisting of roots of irreducible polynomials over $\mathbb Q$ which are the characteristic polynomials of rational symmetric matrices. In particular, every root of such a polynomial must be real, so $x^4-2$ does not have a root in the symmetric closure of $\mathbb Q$. Since $\sqrt[4]{2}$ must exist in a real closed field, this proves that there are fields satisfying the spectral theorem which are not real closed.

[This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/574443/which-polynomials-are-characteristic-polynomials-of-a-symmetric-matrix/1856067#1856067) suggests that it is an unsolved problem to determine which rational polynomials are the characteristic polynomial of a symmetric matrix.

Answer (score 6):

As evidence that there is no easy solution (and in particular, no purely algebraic solution), it is not true over $\mathbb{Q}$ that every monic polynomial is the characteristic polynomial of a normal matrix.  Indeed, direct calculations show that a $2\times 2$ matrix $$\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d\end{pmatrix}$$ is normal iff either $b=c$ or $b=-c$ and $a=d$.  In the first case, the characteristic polynomial is $$x^2-(a+d)x+ad-b^2$$ and in the second case the characteristic polynomial is $$x^2-2ax+a^2+b^2.$$  It is easy to see that over $\mathbb{Q}$ these do not produce all possible monic quadratics; for instance, it is impossible to get $x^2+2$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Eric! After having sunk an unreasonable amount of time into this problem over the last year, I have conclusively determined that an algebraic solution can't exist. See my answer. :)